# Why is my TextBox.Width value not accepting the value I'm trying to assign it?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, tablelayoutpanel

I am trying to evenly space dynamically created controls by giving them a width and height that is a fraction of the width and height of the container control.

However, although my functions calculating the dimensions are correct, for some reason the assignment to the Width property is being stubbornly refused. The WidthToUse() function is returning 19, yet when an attempt is made to assign that vaue to the dynamically created TextBox, it remains at...630! Why 630 to begin with, and why does it refuse to be assigned to?

Even the height, although "working" doesn't work quite right - there are too many controls or not enough space on the panel to accommodate all of the controls using this math.

Here's my code:

```
int WidthToUse = getTextBoxWidthToUse(tableLayoutPanelGreatGooglyMoogly.Width);
int HeightToUse = getControlHeightToUse(tableLayoutPanelGreatGooglyMoogly.Height);

TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
txtbx.Parent = tableLayoutPanelGreatGooglyMoogly;
txtbx.Margin = new Padding();
txtbx.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
txtbx.AutoSize = false;
txtbx.Width = WidthToUse;   // WidthToUse is 19, but txtbx.Width is 630 both before AND after this assignment!
txtbx.Height = HeightToUse; // HeightToUse is 27


private static int getControlHeightToUse(int theDynPanelHeight) {
    return (theDynPanelHeight / NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
}

private static int getTextBoxWidthToUse(int theDynPanelWidth) {
    return (theDynPanelWidth / 32);
}

private static int getLabelWidthToUse(int theDynPanelWidth) {
    return ((theDynPanelWidth / 64) * 3);
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting explicit sizes if your are using DockStyle.Fill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DockStyle.Fill is a property describing the size of a control relative to the size of it's container.  A control will resize to fit all of the empty space in it's parent container with this property set.

Comment: OK, that was true; now the problem is: how do I get the TextBoxes to take up all the space in the "cell" - they cling to the top

Comment: OK, I got it; I feel like a marionette, pulling some strings up, some down, until I hit on the exact right combination to make the parts dance together. What's odd/frustrating is setting the height of the controls to height of the container divided by number of rows doesn't work, nor does setting the width to the width of the container divided by the number of columns.

Comment: I had to set the height divisor to 14 when there are 12 rows. I guess padding or some other "fluff" is causing this off-putting offset.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the `Dock` property set to `Fill` would be my guess.